# JobNotFoundException when I invoke lambda function from Codepipeline in in different account

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-codepipeline

Folks,

Is it possible to get putJobSuccess/putJobFailure result in different account's codepipeline stage? I have a pipeline in one accout that invokes Lambda function in different account. The function runs fine but it is unable to find the JobID (I believe it is looking for the JobID in current account's context).

Answer (score 2):

Job IDs are indeed scoped to an account.

To make this work you'll need to setup a role in the first account, then assume it from the Lambda function in the second account then use those credentials when calling PutJobSuccess/PutJobFailureResult.

There's some documentation on setting up roles here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles.html